# Efficiently finding the sum of a pattern of numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to find the sum of the following series:

$$2\left(\frac{48*49}{2}+\left(\frac{47*48}{2}+\left(\frac{48*49}{2}\right)\left(\frac{2*3}{2}\right)\right)+\left(\frac{46*47}{2}+\left(\frac{47*48}{2}\right)\left(\frac{2*3}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{48*49}{2}\right)\left(\frac{3*4}{2}\right)\right)+\cdots+\left(\frac{1*2}{2}+\left(\frac{2*3}{2}\right)\left(\frac{2*3}{2}\right)+\cdots+\left(\frac{48*49}{2}\right)\left(\frac{48*49}{2}\right)\right)\right)$$

This can be written more simply using sums: 
$$ 2\sum_{i=1}^{48}\left(\frac{i(i+1)}{2}\cdot\sum_{n=1}^{i}\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right) $$

Obviously, it is possible to brute force it, but I am asking for an efficient solution, as it has been eluding me.

Sorry in advance for the length of the expression, I don't know how to format such a long expression.

Comment: You had an extra brace in the second expression before the first \frac.  Extra braces are the most common reason MathJax will not render.  The way I found it was by putting some double dollar signs in the middle and seeing which part rendered, then narrowing down the search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand the second sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^{i}{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}=\frac 12\sum_{n=1}^in^2+n=\frac 12\left(\frac{i(i+1)(2i+1)}6+\frac {i(i+1)}2\right)$$
Now plug that into the first sum and expand.  You will get a sum of constants times powers of $i$ which you can sum using [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula).

Answer (score 0):

We begin with:
$$ 2\sum_{i=1}^{48}\frac{i(i+1)}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{i}{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}} $$

And we have:

$$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n}{2}$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^nk^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^3=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$$

These are all I know from memory, but these formulas can be continued indefinitely.

Let :$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^p=f_p(n)$$

Let us require that $f_p(0)=0$ and $f_p(1)=1$ and let's suppose

$$f_p(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{p+1}c_in^i$$ and require $$f_p(n)=f_p(n+1)-f_p(n)=(n+1)^p$$

Then

$f_{p+1}(n)=\int_0^n(p+1)f_p(x)dx+Cn$ where C is selected so that $f_{p+1}(1)=1$

You'll need to carry this up to the fifth power in order to solve the original problem.